# Error when add Issue Id to a view

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, list-view

I am using SharePoint online, I have created a Content Type in root web, based on Issue and added some extra custom Site Columns to it. In one of the sub webs I have created a Custom List and add my Contetnt type to it. Now when I try to modify the view and add `Issue Id (Linked to item)` field to the view, it generates following error.

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID: ...

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right base type for the list. For an issue tracking list, the list type is "issue", or BaseType="5".

I'm not sure how this works for SharePoint Online. But I have fixed the problem by changing following attribute values:
`Type="1100"` (found in elements.xml, change for both the list and listinstance)
`BaseType="5"` (found in elements.xml and schema.xml of the list )
`Title="IssueList"` (found in schema.xml of the list)